# Group array values using loop and count with Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a series of arrays that I need to group together. Here is an example of the incoming data:

```
[pet_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bob
        [1] => Buster
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => cat
        [1] => dog
    )

[age] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 22
    )

[gender] => Array
    (
        [0] => female
        [1] => male
    )
```

I am trying to group these to get the following result:

```
Pet #1
Name: Bob
Type: Cat
Age: 1
Gender: Female

Pet #2
Name: Buster
Type: Dog
Age: 22
Gender: Male
```

I've tried the following methods without success:

```
# Pet Info
{% set total = pet_name|length %}
{% set count = 0 %}

{% for count in total %}
# Pet #{{count + 1}}
* Name: {{ attribute(pet_name, count) }}
* Type: {{ attribute(type, count) }}
* Age: {{ attribute(age, count) }}
* Gender: {{ attribute(gender, count) }}
{% set count = count + 1 %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Second method:**

```
# Pet Info
{% set count = 0 %}

{% for pet in pet_name %}
# Pet #{{count}}
* Name: {{ attribute(pet_name, count) }}
* Type: {{ attribute(type, count) }}
* Age: {{ attribute(age, count) }}
* Gender: {{ attribute(gender, count) }}

{% set count = count + 1 %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{% for key, i in data['pet_name'] %}
  <ul>
      <li>Pet Num: {{ key + 1}}</li>
      <li>{{ data['pet_name'][key] }}</li>
      <li>{{ data['type'][key] }}</li>
      <li>{{ data['age'][key] }}</li>
      <li>{{ data['gender'][key] }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

It should print:

```
<ul>
    <li>Pet Num: 1</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>female</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Pet Num: 2</li>
    <li>Buster</li>
    <li>dog</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>male</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**: It seems you have an object with arrays, in that case try something like this:

```
{% for key, i in data.pet_name %}
  <ul>
      <li>Pet # {{ key + 1}}</li>
      <li>{{ data.pet_name[key] }}</li>
      <li>{{ data.type[key] }}</li>
      <li>{{ data.age[key] }}</li>
      <li>{{ data.gender[key] }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a reason you used data? The array I have is not under any other array, so I was curious if data is a twig variable, or by declaring data you are assigning the other values to it?

Comment: It's not a twig variable, it's just the name of the variable a passed to the template when I tested it,  based on your sample code I'm gonna assume each category is directly available, so remove all _data._ from my edit, try it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Angelcool got me on the right track. Here is the final solution:

```
{% for key, i in pet_name %}
# #{{key + 1}}
* Name: {{ pet_name[key] }}
* Type: {{ type[key] }}
* Age: {{ age[key] }}
* Gender: {{ gender[key] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Strange this is that this started to work also:

```
# Pet Info
{% set count = 0 %}

{% for pet in pet_name %}
# Pet #{{count}}
* Name: {{ attribute(pet_name, count) }}
* Type: {{ attribute(type, count) }}
* Age: {{ attribute(age, count) }}
* Gender: {{ attribute(gender, count) }}

{% set count = count + 1 %}

{% endfor %}
```